# Swift 5 VIPER template generator (Permission denied)

Tags: swift, viper-architecture

I found this [viper template generator](https://github.com/BinaryBirds/swift-template). I inhaled everything but now I faced with an permission issue.

When I try to execute `swift template generate MyModule --use viper-module` command I got this:

```
error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-template (Permission denied)
```

Before this error I got another one:

```
error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-template (No such file or directory)
```

Not sure if I am on a right way but I just copied swift-template folder into the path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/`

Answer (score 2):

I found this one work for VIPER Template in Swift 5.

https://github.com/zafarivaev/VIPER-Template

## How To Install

1. Clone the repository
2. Navigate to Xcode Templates folder: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/`.
   If 3. Templates folder doesn't exist, create it
3. Copy and paste the VIPER Module.xctemplate in Templates folder

## Use

1. Open Xcode
2. File -> New -> File or ⌘ N
3. Scroll down till you see VIPER Module template and choose it.
4. Set a name for your module. Examples: Home, Auth, SignIn

[image]